# how to apply division tag to make the header appears attached with address bar

Tags: html, css, frontend

How to make websites appear unique in all devices. I have read several websites for this. I don't have a clear idea how to do this. I know bootstrap CSS will help to do this to an extent. How to provide unique front end to users across all devices. Is there any good tutorial for this?

Adding one more question to this, is it possible to make division appear closer to the address bar without any space? If so how to do it?

For example in the following code there is a considerable amount of space between address bar and content when loading page.

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<p>Hello</p>
<--more content-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough, What exactly you want to do? you can't control the browser's controls from HTML

Comment: remove the margin from `body`, browser add margin to `body` that's why it is not attached with top of document. FYI, Chrome adds 8px of `margin`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS:

```
div
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
```

for the block you want to be attached to the address bar. Replace `div` with the name of the class/id/type of the block